# AMD Radeon HD 7350 / Asus HD 7350 Hash Rate

Tags: hash, hashrate

What hash rate can I expect from an AMD Radeon HD 7350?

Additional Info: 
CPU: Intel i5-3450 @ 3.10GHz / 4 CPUs 
RAM: 4gb (4096MB) 
MoBo: Asus CM6630_CM6730_CM6830 
OS: Windows 10 Pro

Any inputs are highly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cards with that GPU usually have between 256 Mb and 1 Gb of memory, not enough to mine Ether.